# Not all variables in .env are cached after run php artisan config:cache

Tags: laravel-5

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=../storage/app/service-account.json

I have a google api credential key in the .env file. However, after I run php artisan config:cache, the credential could not be loaded. It works fine before rhe caching the configuration.

I found the following function in the google api auth file in vendor folder. It seems the google service use the .env by default. So after config:cache, the fromEnv function breaks. 
Use another auth method setAuthConfig('/path/to/client_credentials.json') solve the problem.

```
/**
 * Load a JSON key from the path specified in the environment.
 *
 * Load a JSON key from the path specified in the environment
 * variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. Return null if
 * GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is not specified.
 *
 * @return array JSON key | null
 */
public static function fromEnv()
{
    $path = getenv(self::ENV_VAR);
    if (empty($path)) {
        return;
    }
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        $cause = 'file ' . $path . ' does not exist';
        throw new \DomainException(self::unableToReadEnv($cause));
    }
    $jsonKey = file_get_contents($path);
    return json_decode($jsonKey, true);
}
```

Comment: how are you using the env variable in config.php, can you show that?

Comment: I do not understand. It is a cache file with DB and email config like DB_DATABASE and MAIL_USERNAME.

Comment: Did you add the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable to the config files or do you only have it in the `.env` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the way you load the file.

You probably have this in your view/controller: `env('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ');`. But this will break when you do `php artisan config:cache`. You should only use the config() helper in your views/controller. So in order to make that work, you should make a extra google-config file or add the following to your config/services.php:

```
 'google' => [
    'application-credentials' => env('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'),
 ]
```

Now you can fetch that inside your views/controller:

```
config('services.google.application-credentials');
```

Comment: Thanks. The Google API Service use getenv by default. Use another auth method solve the problem.

Comment: @Hans can you please provide a clear example on how you actually managed to solve this issue? I am not using `env('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ');` anywhere in my code and Google\Auth package is using (like you already mentioned) getenv() by default

Comment: @DanielR.  `$client = new Google_Client(); ` `$client->setAuthConfig(path to service-account.json);`

Answer (score 0):

If your value for env contains space then you need to enclose it in quote. i.e. APP_NAME="This is myapp". Please confirm it first.

In your case try with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="../storage/app/service-account.json"

Answer (score 0):

First run

```
 php artisan cache:clear
```

Then

```
 php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Already tried. I think it is the problem of "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=../storage/app/service-account.json"